# Set Interval in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a button and textbox like this :

```
<button type="submit" id="go" style="width: 20px; height: 30px;"></button>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
```

and i want to write a script that when i write a number in the textbox and click on button, it add one to mynumber(which i write on textbox) every 5 second. I wrote this script but it is not work! what is the problem?
my script :

```
$("document").ready(
        function () {
            $("#go").click(
                function () {
                    setInterval(
                        function () {
                            var values = $("txt").text();
                            values = values + 1;
                            $("txt").html(values);
                        }, 400);
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few issues as shown below

```
//it is document not 'document'
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer;
    $("#go").click(function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            //use id selector and .val() to get the value
            var values = $("#txt").val();
            //parse the string to int before adding 1
            values = parseInt(values) + 1;
            $("#txt").val(values);
        }, 5000); //5 seconds is 5000 milli seconds
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n7rut/)

Answer (score 2):

You should change:

- `$("txt")` to `$("#txt")`
- `$("txt").text();` to `$("txt").val();`
- `$("txt").html(values);` to `$("txt").val(values);`

Correct JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/eMbxp/

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$("#txt").val()
```

instead of

```
$("txt").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This : 
its Running :

```
$("document").ready(
    function () {
        $("#go").click(
            function () {
                setInterval(
                    function () {
                        var values = $("#txt").val();  //use .val() to take data from input element.
              values = Number(values)+1;    //var is not a integer so you have to put ,it inside a Number() 
                        $("#txt").val(values); // use Id selector ' # ' in jQuery to select a element.
                    }, 5000);
            });
    });
```